# Windows can not find 'gpedit.msc'. Make sure you typed the name correctly

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I have windows server 2003 standard edition sp2 64 bit and I have OU groups to apply policies like WSUS, deploying programs..etc, I had updated of administrative tools pack so I decide to install Windows Server 2003 R2 Administration Tools Pack (x64) after the installation I had problem when I tried to open policies from Active Directory Users and Computers right-click on OU then group policy try to edit on of the policies there is an error message said

windows can not find 'gpedit.msc'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again. to search for a file, click the start button, and click Search.

Another message said:
Failed to start the Group policy snapin. The gpedit.msc file may be missing, files with .msc extension may not be associated with mmc.exe, or you may not have the appropriate rights.

Details:
The system cannot find the file specified.
Any advice would be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy `gpedit.msc` from `c:\windows\system32` to `c:\windows\syswow64`.

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: my c:\windows\system32 only had a gpedit.dll but the c:\windows\syswow64 had gpedit.msc